# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $d'$ be the [standard bounded metric][1] corresponding to $d.$ Then, $(X,d)$ is complete iff $(X,d')$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $d'$ be the [standard bounded metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927386/are-d-and-d-min-dx-y-1-strongly-equivalent) corresponding  to $d.$ Then, $(X,d)$ is complete iff $(X,d')$ is complete

From the answers it is clear that both metric spaces are not strongly equivalent. $\{x_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence with respect to $d$ implies $\{x_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence with respect to $d'$.If  $(X,d)$ is complete then $\{x_n\}$ coverges to some point in $x\in X$ with respect to $d$. $\{x_n\}$ coverges to some point in $x\in X$  with respect to $d'$.How do I prove the converse?

Comment: I would like to present a brief simple proof but first I want to confirm that you know that $d,d'$ are equivalent metrics (i,e, they generate the same topology) and  that you don't want a proof of that also.

Comment: yes.i know that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof should go like this:-

Part I: If $\left( X, d \right)$ is complete, then $\left( X, d' \right)$ is complete.

To prove this, we need to start with a Cauchy sequence in $\left( X, d' \right)$. So, let $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d'$. Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n, m \geq n_0, d' \left( x_n, x_m \right) < \epsilon$. In particular, this is true for $\epsilon < 1$ and hence we shall get $\forall 0 < \epsilon < 1, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n, m \geq n_0, d' \left( x_n, x_m \right) < \epsilon < 1$. Now, $d' \left( x_n, x_m \right) = \min \left\lbrace d \left( x_n, x_m \right) \right\rbrace$. Since $d' \left( x_n, x_m \right) < 1$, we have $\min \left\lbrace d \left( x_n, x_m \right) \right\rbrace = d \left( x_n, x_m \right)$. Hence, the sequence $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ is convergent with respect to the metric $d$. Let it converge to $x$. Now, our claim is that the sequence converges to the same limit in $\left( X, d' \right)$ as well. I think this can be easily done and encourage you to try it!

Part II: If $\left( X, d' \right)$ is complete then $\left( X, d \right)$ is complete.

To prove this, we start with a Cauchy sequence in $\left( X, d \right)$. So, let that Cauchy sequence be $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$. We have, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n, m > n_0, d \left( x_n, x_m \right) < \epsilon$. Now, $d' \left( x_n, x_m \right) = \min \left\lbrace d \left( x_n, x_m \right), 1 \right\rbrace \leq d \left( x_n, x_m \right) < \epsilon$ for the same stage $n_0$. Thus, the sequence is Cauchy in $\left( X, d' \right)$ and hence is convergent in $\left( X, d' \right)$. Now, we need to prove that if it converges to $x \in \left( X, d' \right)$, then it converges to the same limit in $\left( X, d \right)$. Again, I encourage you to try it on your own!

Comment: for first proof, $d'(x_n,x) \leq d(x_n,x)\$.right?

Comment: part 2, $\epsilon<1,d'(x_n,x) = d(x_n,x)$.right?

Comment: Yes, but that will not directly give $d \left( x_n, x \right) < \epsilon$. Also, what is your second comment?

Comment: what is the problem with the first part? for $\epsilon>0,\exists N(\epsilon): \forall n\ge  N(\epsilon) ,d'(x_n,x)< \epsilon[\because$ inequality in the first comment ]

Comment: Kindly go through the proof again! I think you are confused in what to be taken as hypothesis and what is need to be proven. You should always keep in mind that no proof, for whatsoever reason, should contain a circular argument. Because, in that case, your proof will not be valid.

Comment: where is the problem? $x_n$ converges to $x$ in(X, d).also, we have d'\leq d. so by this inequality , $x_n$ converges w.r.t d'. where is the circular statement coming here?

Comment: Of course, this is correct! I thought, you were telling about the proof you gave. Actually, what you gave has a circular argument in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83610/discussion-between-math-geek-and-aniruddha-deshmukh).

Answer (score 1):

We have $d'=\min (1,d).$ Let $\{d_1,d_2\}=\{d,d'\},$ i.e. $(d_1=d\land d_2=d')  \lor (d_1=d' \land d_2=d).$

If $d_1$ is complete and $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is any $d_2$-Cauchy sequence then there exists $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that  $\forall m,n>n_0\;(d_2(x_m,x_n)<1).$ So  $\forall m,n>n_0\;(d_1(x_m,x_n)=d_2(x_m,x_n)).$ So $\lim_{s\to \infty} \sup_{m>n>s}d_1(x_m,x_n)=\lim_{s\to \infty}\sup_{m>n>s}d_2(x_m,x_n)=0.$

So $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is also a $d_1$-Cauchy sequence, and since $d_1$ is complete, there exists $x$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d_1(x,x_n)=0.$

Now there are only finitely many $n$ for which $d(x,x_n)\geq 1,$ so $d_2(x,x_n)=d_1(x,x_n)$ for all but finitely many $n.$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty }d_2(x,x_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}d_1(x,x_n)=0. $